# How to calculate the average salary?

Tags: mean

I have data on the average, median, minimum, maximum salary for employees with experience from one to three years and with experience from three to seven years. Is it possible to assume based on these data what the average or median salary will be for employees with experience from **three** to **four** years? If it can be calculated, it would be ideal to get a formula for counting.

Sample data:

|  | Minimum | First quartile (Q1) | Median | Average | The third quartile (Q3) | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| employees with experience from one to three years | 100 | 700 | 1250 | 1449 | 2000 | 4300 |
| employees with experience from three years to seven | 150 | 2175 | 3000 | 3080 | 3650 | 7500 |

(English is not my native language, so I apologize if I made mistakes).

Comment: I would guess that the mean for that group would be between the two means cited, but any precise number depends on extra assumptions.

Comment: "I would guess that the mean for that group would be between the two means cited". Typically, it is correct since salary is often higher with more years of experience. However, mathematically, we cannot say anything.

Comment: I would say No, we can't. Information about 3-4 years have lost when we converted the raw data into a summary table like that. If we want to go back, we can only make model-assumptions (guesses) that fit well with whatever information left here, which takes some effort.

Comment: Nick Cox, thanks a lot for the suggested solution